# Add/remove class to label tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came up with this jQuery snippet to add/remove a class on `<label>` tags that contain either checkboxes or radio buttons, in order to improve usability so users can see what item(s) they have selected.

But I would like to know if there's a way to optimize the code (or not if that's the case).

```
$('label input[type=radio], label input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  $('label:has(input:checked)').addClass('active');
  $('label:has(input:not(:checked))').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you've marked this question answered, but since this website is about 'code review', and further improvements are possible

You're currently attaching event-handlers on each checkbox, which is inefficient, it's far more efficient to use 'delegation', making use of event-bubbling. Reducing the amount of event-handlers is better for performance and reduces the risk for memory-leaks, especially if you're adding/removing elements to your page dynamically.

More information on Event Delegation:

In general: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

jQuery.on(): http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

With jQuery, you can make use of 'delegation' by putting a .on() event handler on a parent element. A performance comparison can be found here
http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/34

(although you're not using the .live() function, it is to illustrate using separate event-handlers vs. a single handler/delegation)

Here's some information that explains how it works:
http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/

For your specific example, the code would be like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'label input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $(this.parentNode).toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
```

This will create a *single* event-handler that handles *all* click events on 'checkboxes' *if they are wrapped in a label* like this:

```
<label><input type='checkbox' id='check1' value='1' />Check me</label>
```

**However**, if you don't 'wrap' your input in a label, but have them separate, using the 'for' attribute:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='check1' value='1' />  <label for='check1'>check me</label>
```

Then the code above won't work, in this case you'll have to select the label in a different way:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Very well explained, and the link references are a great help. You also addressed different situations (`<input>`s inside and outside the `<label>`), which can certainly happen down the road. Did not know about the concept of 'delegation' until now. Thanks a million for all the information.

Comment: @Ricardo glad I was able to help. Kinda made it my mission to try to educate people a bit. Hoping other people will read and learn as well

Comment: If we want to squeeze out every bit of performance, you should replace `$(this).attr('id')` with simply `this.id`.

Comment: @JosephSilber good suggestion, I'll modify my answer

Answer (score 3):

You're adding a `click` handler to all your inputs, and then implementing the `click` handler such that each click processes *all* the labels.  This is probably not what you want.

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('label input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $(this.parentNode).toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});

$('label input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').each(function(){
        $(this.parentNode).toggleClass('active', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Happily enough, that approach is also more efficient, as it's processing 1 element per click for checkboxes instead of `n` elements per click.  For radio buttons it still has to process multiple elements, but the number processed is still less than the total number of elements on the page (assuming the page contains more than a single group of radio buttons).

Here's a live example:  http://jsfiddle.net/DfU3R/3/

As nickles80 rightly notes, however, the performance difference between the two approaches will likely be negligible, and premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Although `$(elem.parentNode)` is better than `$(elem).parent()` performance-wise, I think you should use the latter. If you're using jQuery, use it properly.

Comment: Also, instead of that bloated `applyClass` function, just use `toggleClass`; it takes a second parameter as a boolean: `$(this).parent().toggleClass('active', this.checked);`

Comment: Well spotted on the second point, it's much more compact using `toggleClass()`.  On the first point, however, I have to disagree.  Using jQuery properly doesn't necessarily mean giving it a monopoly on all DOM accesses.

Comment: @aroth Yes, as I mentioned on *nickles80*'s answer, if there's a case where it is necessary to have long forms with loads of check boxes and radio buttons, I would like the page to perform as efficiently as possible, which means that your suggested improved snippet seems to do exactly that. Will certainly consider it for the future. Thanks a lot for the jsfiddle demo as well.

Comment: @Ricardo Read my answer below; For long forms, event delegation is the best approach

Answer (score 1):

You are probably pretty good here.

You might be able to micro optimize by only highlighting / un-highlighting the corresponding label of the input but unless you have 100s of labels on your form I wouldn't bother.  Especially since the radio button implementation would not be simple.

The only caveat I have is that if you have a label with the class active that has an input of any type (textbox) that class will also be removed upon clicking any of the checkboxes.  But I doubt that really matters for you.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/

"Don't optimize until you need to."

Comment: *"Don't optimize until you need to."*-- Hmm, I would've never thought of this when writing JavaScript; I'm clearly just starting with JS. Nonetheless, yes, when it comes to forms I try to keep them as short as possible, but if there's a case where it is necessary to have long forms with loads of check boxes and radio buttons, I would like the page to perform as efficiently as possible. I think I'll leave what I have as is since I only have a couple of radio buttons and checkboxes on the form I'm implementing this snippet on. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nickles80 this website is about 'code review' - try to assist people to get their code as good as possible and correct mistakes or bad practice. *Even* if you *normally* wouldn't optimize the code (e.g. the code is part of an admin page that is only used once a month, where performance isn't a big issue)

Comment: @thaJeztah That is fair.  But he specifically asked if it needed it.  I didn't think it did.  Optimizing this snippet would take it from 4 lines to probably somewhere around 50.  And _might_ be a little faster.  Sometimes in reviewing code, the code doesn't need any improvements.